# screen - move cursor to beginning of line

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

In bash I can usually move the cursor to the beginning of the line using `CTRL+a`.

In screen, `CTRL+a` is being used for the special screen-commands.

How can I a) use another key-combination for the screen-commands or b) use another combination to move the cursor to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To send a Ctrl-A to your application, i.e. bash, from within `screen`, type

```
Ctrl-A a
```

Comment: Perfect! Going to use this.

Comment: How do you do this in a tcsh screen session? When I try your suggestion, it just beeps.