# screen - move cursor to beginning of line *in tcsh*

Tags: gnu-screen, tcsh

I am a `screen` noob.  I also prefer to use tcsh.  I cannot figure out the shortcut for getting to the beginning of the line (e.g. `control-a`).

When I try to suggestion here:

[screen - move cursor to beginning of line](https://superuser.com/questions/614781/screen-move-cursor-to-beginning-of-line)

The terminal just beeps.  Do I have to bind a new key combo or is there some existing shortcut to accomplish this?

Comment: Also, when I down-arrow to the bottom of my history, I see `"   Wuff  -----  Wuff!!   "`.  The admin said that had something to do with the top of the hour, but I always see it is I down-arrow at the end of my history when I'm in a screen session.

Comment: Also, another annoying side-effect of screen is that I cannot triple-click to select an entire soft-wrapped line. If I click and drag to select an entire soft-wrapped line and copy, it inserts hard-returns. Ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> suggestion from the link you posted works for me when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> (i.e. no <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in the first part) (whereas it beeps if you hold down shift too).